# Calculate variance as $n \to \infty$ using the covariance

Tags: probability, covariance, probability-limit-theorems

Consider $X_1, ..., X_n,...$  independent random variables for which $\text{Var}(X_i) = \sqrt{i}$. Let $Y_i=f(X_i, X_{i+1}), f:R^2\to R$. Show that $cov(Y_i,Y_j)=0$ for $|i-j|>2$ and then show that the variance of $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

I have:
$Cov[Y_i,Y_j]=E[Y_i,Y_j]-E[Y_i]E[Y_j]$. As $Y_i$ is a transformation of the random variables $X_i, X_{i+1}$, the covariance can be rewritten as (omitting constants):

$=E[(aX_i+bX_{i+1} ),(cX_j+dX_{j+1} )]-E[(aX_i+bX_{i+1} )]E[cX_j+dX_{j+1}]$.

Take $|i-j|>2$ and use the independence of $X_1,...,X_n$, it follows that the covariance can be rewritten as:

$=E[(aX_i+bX_{i+1})]E[cX_j+dX_{j+1} ]-E[(aX_i+bX_{i+1} )]E[cX_j+dX_{j+1}]\\=E[Y_i]E[Y_j]-E[Y_i]E[Y_j]=0$

I guess this is correct, but I suppose this is not the kind of proof they are asking for. Can anyone give me a hint to give a better proof?

For the second part, I suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}Y_i= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}Cov[Y_i,Y_j]\neq  \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}0$, as the second part also assumes the case that $|i-j|\leq2$. Could anyone give me a hint there too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1: When $|i -j|\geq 2$ the Random Variables $Y_i,Y_j$ depend on are independent of each other. For example, $$Y_1 = f(X_1, X_2), Y_3 = f(X_3, X_4)$$  This implies that $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent and therefore have no correlation.

Part 2: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right) &=& \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \text{Cov}(Y_i, Y_j) \\
    &=& \frac{1}{n^2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(Y_i) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \text{Cov}(Y_i, Y_{i+1})\right) \\
    &\leq& \frac{1}{n^2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(Y_i) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{\text{Var}(Y_i)\text{Var}(Y_{i+1}})\right) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

The third line follows because $\text{Cov}(X, Y) \leq \sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)}$.

Comment: I was studying the third line, but I don't understand why that holds. The variance of $X_i=\sqrt{i}$, so how comes that all $Y_i$ are i.d.?

Comment: @Holograph  I did read the question as saying they where identically distributed.  I'll think more on it.

Comment: That was given in the excersise, I should have written that at the start of this question. But then I suppose that inequality still is true as $Cov[X,Y]\leq \sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}$, right?

Comment: @Holograph  Yes, that inequality is still true.  Do you know anything about what the function $f$ looks like?  You seemed to think it was affine in your partial solution.  (Feel free to uncheck this as the answer, I did read it incorrectly).

Comment: No, I assumed $f(X_i,X_j)$ should be some combination of $aX_i+c+bX_{i+1}+d$